# How to catch the post values from angular2 into my php file at localhost

Tags: php, angular

When I post value from angular2 using services from my ng server, http://localhost:4200 to my localhost XAMPP server http://localhost/test/catch_angular_post.php and tring to catch value using $_POST OR $_REQUEST but It's showing Empty Array,

Here is My services Code :

```
const contactData  =
{
    full_name:frmValue['name'],
    email:frmValue['email'],
    phone:frmValue['phone'],
    message:frmValue['message']
};

const headers = new Headers();
var timestamp = (new Date).getTime();
headers.append('Content-Type','application/json;charset=utf-8');
this.http.post('http://localhost/test/catch_angular_post.php',JSON.stringify(contactData),headers).subscribe(()=>console.log('Success'),err=>console.log(err));
```

And here is my PHP code is :

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Can Anyone Help me Out ?

Comment: fisr decode your json in your php like print_r(json_decode($_POST, true);

Answer (score 0):

simply just try this code into your php file if the post is successful from angular2 :

```
<?php 
    $value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); 
    print_r($value);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not an Array, but an Object you are sending. I think your problem is when assigning values to be sent to backend.

Since it seems you are using a form and assigning values from that. They way you then can access your values is extracting them from the value passed to the submit, or by:

```
this.frmValue.get('name').value
```

But if you have your submit, you can work with the values like this:

```
submit(value) { // here you pass `frmValue.value` when you submit form
  console.log(value.name)
}
```

So check that you are actually sending values to the backend!